# Cambio en el comportamiento de los controles Edit al recibir el Foco, por migración de Genexus 17 a Genexus 18

Tags: genexus

Al migrar de Genexus 17 a Genexus 18 cambió el comportamiento al hacer clic en los controles Edit. En GX17 al hacer clic en un Edit, el cursor se colocaba en la posición del contenido del Edit donde se hizo el clic, mientras que ahora en GX18 al hacer clic sobre un Edit se selecciona automáticamente todo su contenido, sin poder editar con el mouse. ¿Cómo podría configurar en GX18 el comportamiento anterior como en GX17? (Usamos el entorno Java), gracias